# Can a UDP multicast socket be configured so that write() can be called rather than sendto()?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, multicast

I am writing a C++ multicasting application on Linux Ubuntu.

In my C++ multicast sender class I do this:

```
uint16_t port = 5678;
const char* group = "239.128.128.128";

int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(group);
addr.sin_port = htons(port);

const char* buf = "Hi there";
size_t bytes_to_write = 8;

size_t bytes_sent = sendto(fd, buf, bytes_to_write, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

Is there any way to configure the file descriptor so that I can call write() rather than sendto()? I would have thought there would be a setsockopt option or similar to do this?

Comment: You could try using [`connect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html).  For `SOCK_DGRAM` that would normally set the default destination address.  Haven't ever tried it with an ip multicast address though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Per the documentation [man 7 udp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html)

> When
>          connect(2) is called on the socket, the default destination address
>          is set and datagrams can now be sent using send(2) or write(2)
>          without specifying a destination address.

and, for generality, the POSIX spec for [connect](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/connect.html) says

> If the initiating socket is not connection-mode, then connect() shall set the socket's peer address, and no connection is made. For SOCK_DGRAM sockets, the peer address identifies where all datagrams are sent on subsequent send() functions, and limits the remote sender for subsequent recv() functions.

It's always worth checking the documentation for these, things, it isn't *that* impenetrable. FWIW I couldn't remember immediately whether you need `connect()` or `bind()` for this, and it took me a few seconds to find out.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the send and sendto man pages but it didn't have quite what I was looking for. Stevens also describes connect() for UDP but I read it for the unicast context.

Comment: Ah, yeah - OK, they are _fairly_ impenetrable. At least, it's always easier to find something if you already know it exists.